# Firebase functions take several minutes

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I created a Firebase cloud function that does the following: With a given email, the user is deleted from the auth service and then a document from Firestore is updated. It does work, but it takes several minutes (roughly 3) to make these changes to auth and firestore. Here's the code:

`

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.deleteUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

const userEmail = data.userEmail;

admin.auth().getUserByEmail(userEmail)
    .then(userRecord => {
        userUID = userRecord.uid
        admin.auth().deleteUser(userUID)
        admin.firestore().collection("instructors").get().then((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                const docID = doc.id
                const documentData = doc.data()
                var studentsData = documentData["students"]
                const studentsList = Object.keys(studentsData).map(String)
                if (studentsList.indexOf(userUID) !== -1) {
                    delete studentsData[userUID]
                    return admin.firestore().collection("instructors").doc(docID).update({students: studentsData})
                }
            })
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log("Error deleting user from Firestore: ", error)
        })
        return
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('User successfully deleted');
        return
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error deleting user: ', error)
    })
});`
```

On the webpage, this debug information shows up:

9:06:22.925 PM

deleteUser
Function execution started

9:06:23.365 PM

deleteUser
Callable request verification passed

9:06:23.369 PM

deleteUser
Function execution took 446 ms, finished with status code: 200

9:06:33.752 PM

These messages are comning in right after the function is triggered, as it should, but the mentioned changes take much longer to process.

Comment: You must return a promise that becomes fulfilled with the response to send to the client.  You're not returning anything right now, which means the function terminates immediately and may not finish any of the async work.  I suggest reviewing the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#sending_back_the_result

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning anything from the top-level code in your function, which means that Cloud Functions may terminate the container right after the closing `}` has run, which is usually well before the asynchronous call to Firestore has completed.

The first step is to add a `return` here:

```
exports.deleteUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

  const userEmail = data.userEmail;

  // 
  return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(userEmail)
    ...
```